# How do I do Mongoid 1:N:M with a field

Tags: mongoid, relation

I'm trying to describe a 1:N M:1 relationship with the linking table containing an extra fields of info.  Both table1 and table3 both have a lot of fields.

The existing table looks like this:

```
Table1      1:N   Table2       M:1   Table3
somethings        extra info         otherthings
id                table1_id          id
                  table3_id
```

The table2.extra info is messing things up for me.  How do I describe this in mongoid?

```
class Model1
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :somethings, :type => String
  has_many_and_belongs_to :inbetween
end

class ModelInbetween
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :extra_info, :type => String

  ???
end

class Model2
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :otherthings, :type => String

  has_many_and_belongs_to :inbetween
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mongoid, `has_many` and `belongs_to` are used to express a `1:N` relationship between two collections. `has_many_and_belongs_to` is only used for `N:N` relationships. See [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many) for the official documentation. As far as I can tell, your tables should look like this:

```
class Model1
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :somethings, :type => String
  has_many :modelInbetweens
end

class ModelInbetween
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :extra_info, :type => String

  belongs_to :model1
  belongs_to :model2

end

class Model2
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :otherthings, :type => String

  has_many :modelinbetweens
end
```

Also, make sure to pay attention to whether the plural/singular form of the model should be used in defining the relationships.

Comment: I'll have to give this a try tomorrow!